# SCLAlert pod Icon resizing

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I am using SCLAlert pod (https://cocoapods.org/pods/SCLAlertView). I am trying to change the size of the icon `kCircleIconHeight`. As it is a pod file, I click into the following folders to access its swift file: Pods -> SCLAlertView -> SCLAlertView.swift. 
The file is locked from editing so I unlock it to edit it. I try altering the `kCircleIconHeight` value in the `public init` section, but that doesn't work.

I then try and use `let appearance = SCLAlertView.SCLAppearance( kCircleIconHeight: 55.0, showCircularIcon: true )` in the `ViewDidAppear` function but this still doesn't work.
how can I change this value?